# Washington DC to Hampton / Newport News by Ferry

Tags: usa, ferries, washington-dc, riverboats

I wonder if it is possible and how much it would cost to travel from Washington DC to Newport News (or somewhere near) by boat along the Potomac River?

Answer (score 8):

There is **no long-distance water transportation to or from Washington, D.C.** The nearest cruise terminal is [Cruise Baltimore](http://www.cruise.maryland.gov/). Similarly, there is no long-distance commercial passenger water transportation from Newport News; the nearest terminal is [Cruise Virginia](https://nauticus.org/about-cruise-virginia/), and the last major cruise line, Carnival, left in 2013. As far as I can tell, there are no services between Baltimore and Norfolk, either; the vast majority of passenger boat traffic is headed for Florida or the Bahamas.

Considering how ridiculous I-95 traffic is, especially now with the massive [95 Express Lanes](https://expresslanes.com/) construction project underway, you'd think a boat service would be commercially feasible, but as of now, your best road alternative is probably Amtrak. There is Northeast Corridor service connecting Washington to Newport News two or three times a day, and daily service from Washington to Norfolk.

---

Incidentally, Washington has no commuter ferries, either, though such services have been [proposed and studied for decades](http://www.washingtonpost.com/local/will-dc-area-residents-commute-by-water/2011/06/03/AGNQeFNH_story.html). The nearest ferry crossing is [White's Ferry](https://www.facebook.com/WhitesFerry), about an hour northwest of downtown in light traffic.

Locally, there are a handful of water taxi services and dinner cruise companies connecting certain points in and close to the city during tourist season. Not all companies serve all locations, and the hours of each operation are also highly variable. For example, water taxis to Nationals Park operate only when there are baseball games or major concerts. The stops include

- [Alexandria, Virginia waterfront](https://www.visitalexandriava.com/things-to-do/waterfront-activities/) (aka Old Town)
- Georgetown waterfront (31st & K St NW, D.C., at the [Washington Harbour](https://www.thewashingtonharbour.com/) complex)
- [National Harbor](https://www.nationalharbor.com/) (Prince Georges County, Maryland)
- National Mall (West Basin and Ohio Drives NW, D.C.).
- Nationals Park (aka [Diamond Teague Park](https://www.capitolriverfront.org/go/diamond-teague-park), Capitol Waterfront, South East Waterfront)
- Southwest Waterfront (D.C., inc. [The Wharf](https://www.wharfdc.com/))

Comment: From the map of that area it looks like it should be really beautiful, in particular with a ferry going along the coast-line would be nice. I cannot understand why this is not available. Perhaps it is? I will look carefully into all the links you provided, thanks. I wish I could give you more points for your post though.

Comment: It is not enough for a route to be beautiful; it must be profitable as well. The landscape is not particularly unique, making it hard to sell as a sightseeing trip, and the route is long and not particularly convenient, making it hard to sell to travelers compared to the freeway, rail, and air alternatives.